# How can I define a column prefix with Entity Framework Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following model:

```
public class TranscoderConfiguration {

    public int                Id                    { get; set; }
    public NetworkEndpoint    SourceEndpoint        { get; set; }
    public NetworkEndpoint    DestinationEndpoint   { get; set; }

}

public class NetworkEndpoint {

    public byte[] Address { get; set; }
    public int    Port    { get; set; }

}
```

Now EF tries to map the code first model this way:

```
    Id    |    Address    |    Port    |    Address    |    Port
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which obviously doesn't work. How can I define that EF should map complex types prefixed by their property name? Such as SourceEndpoint.Address etc?

Comment: I am surprised that this works at all. You haven't defined a key in `NetworkEndpoint` and you should be getting "EntityType 'NetworkEndpoint' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType" when you add a migration. Have you missed something out?

Comment: I have no idea how it worked, but you may want to add `[ComplexType]` Attribute to `NetworkEndpoint`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674883/add-column-name-convention-to-ef6-fluentapi